Setting environmental variable for my process, should I use http or https(c#). Does this affect setting proxy for my process?
Currently I am trying to make my process go through proxy and I am using,
string proxyEnvVariable = "https_proxy";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envKey, envString);
But in somecase clients use "http proxy server" does setting environmental variable with "https_proxy" for http affect the way it works or can I continue to use the same.
Please advice.
string proxyEnvVariable = "https_proxy";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envKey, envString);

You are trying to make a HTTP Client - Server connection.  A secure connection is encrypted.  The S in HTTPS stands for secure.  Some servers are not secure and use HTTP.  Other server are secure and use HTTPS.  While others can use either HTTP or HTTPS.  A proxy will always use HTTPS because a proxy is used to establish a secure connection.

Sorry for the confusion. The http I mentioned here is my proxy server (eg: http:// proxy.example.com:8080) . Hence the proxy takes http would setting the environment with https_proxy be a problem. eg : Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("https_proxy", "http ://proxy.example.com:8080");

What is reading the environmental variable?  Setting does nothing unless something is reading the variable.

My intent here is to make all the outbound traffic from my application to go through the proxy which I am setting particularly for that process.
